# Does anyone know how to add row numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can open this file directly from the net,and I want to add row numbers to each line based on rules. If you need header row number,then start from number 1, if no need, then start from next line. This is my code, I tried a lot but doesn't work. It looks like picture. Does anyone how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
import sys
class Main:
    def task1(self):
        print('*' * 30, 'Task')
        import urllib.request
        # url
        url = 'http://www.born.nhely.hu/group_list.txt'
        # Initiate a request to get a response
        while True:
            try:
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            except Exception as e:
                print('An error has occurred, the request is being made again, the error message is as follows：', e)
            else:
                break
        # Print all student information
        content = response.read().decode('utf-8')
        
        #add row number
        header_row = input("Do you want to know header_row numbers? Y OR N?")
        if header_row == 'Y':
            for i, line in enumerate(content, start=1):
                print(f'{i},{line}')
        else:
            for i, line in enumerate(content, start=0):
                print('{},{}'.format(i, line.strip()))
        
        
    def start(self):
        self.task1()

Main().start()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the data you are downloading:

```
Name;Short name;Email;Country;Other spoken languages
ABOUELHASSAN Shehab Ibrahim Adbelazin;?;dwedar909@gmail.com;?;?
AGHAEI HOSSEIN ABADI Mohammad Mehdi;Matt;mahdiaghaei355@gmail.com;Iran;English
...
```

Now look at the results you are getting:

```
1,N
2,a
3,m
4,e
5,;
6,S
7,h
8,o
...
```

It should be apparent that you are looping character by character; not line by line.

When you have:

```
for i, line in enumerate(content, start=1):
                print(f'{i},{line}')
```

`content` is a string -- not a list of lines -- so you will loop over the string character by character with the `for` loop.

So to fix, do:

```
for i, line in enumerate(content.splitlines(), start=1):
    print(f'{i},{line}')
```

Or, you can change the method of reading from the server to reading lines instead of characters:

```
content = response.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your absorbing the .txt content in one big string... if you use .readlines() instead of .read(), you can achieve what you want.

You should modify this:

```
# Print all student information
 content = response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

To this:

```
# Print all student information
 content = response.readlines()
```

You can use the `repr()` method to take a look at your data:

```
print(repr(content))
'Name;Short name;Email;Country;Other spoken languages\r\nABOUELHASSAN Shehab Ibrahim Adbelazin;?;dwedar909@gmail.com;?;?\r\nAGHAEI HOSSEIN ABADI Mohammad Mehdi;Matt;mahdiaghaei355@gmail.com;Iran;English\r\nAMIN Asjad;?;;?;?\r\nATILA Arda Burak;Arda;arda_atila@hotmail.com;Turkey;English\r\nBELTRAN CASTRO Carlos Ricardo;Ricardo;crbeltrancas@gmail.com;Colombia;English, Chinese\r\nBhatti Muhammad Hasan;?;;?;?\r\nCAKIR Alp Hazar;Alp;alphazarc@gmail.com;Turkey;English\r\nDENG Zhihui;Deng;dzhfalcon0727@gmail.com;China;English\r\nDURUER Ahmet Enes;Ahmet / kahverengi;hello@ahmetduruer.com;Turkey;English\r\nENKHZAYA Jagar;Jager;japman2400@gmail.com;Mongolia;English\r\nGHAIBAH Sanaa;Sanaa;sanaagheibeh12@gmail.com;Syria;English\r\nGUO Ruizheng;?;ruizhengguo@gmail.com;China;English\r\nGURBANZADE Gurban;Qurban;gurbanzade01@gmail.com;Azeribaijan;English, Russian, Turkish\r\nHASNAIN Syed Muhammad;Hasnain;syedhasnainhijazy313@gmail.com;Pakistan;?\r\nISMAYILOV Firdovsi;Firi;firiisi@gmail.com;Azeribaijan ?;English,Russian,Turkish\r\nKINGRANI Muskan;Muskan;muskankingrani4@gmail.com;India;English\r\nKOKO Susan Kekeli Ruth;Susan;susankoko3@gmail.com;Ghana;N/A\r\nKOLA-OLALEYE Adeola Damilola;Adeola;inboxadeola@gmail.com;Nigeria;French\r\nLEWIS Madison Buse;?;madisonbuse@yahoo.com;Turkey;Turkish\r\nLI Ting;Ting;514053044@qq.com;China;English\r\nMARUSENKO Svetlana;Svetlana;svetlana.maru@gmail.com;Russia;English, German\r\nMOHANTY Cyrus;cyrus;cyrusmohanty5261@gmail.com;India;English\r\nMOTHOBI Thabo Emmanuel;thabo;thabomothobi@icloud.com;South Africa;English\r\nNayudu Yashmit Vinay;?;;?;?\r\nPurevsuren Davaadorj;?;Purevsuren.davaadorj99@gmail.com;Mongolia ?;English\r\nSAJID Anoosha;Anoosha;anooshasajid12@gmail.com;Pakistan;English\r\nSHANG Rongxiang;Xiang;1074482757@qq.com;China;English\r\nSU Haobo;Su;2483851740@qq.com;China;English\r\nTAKEUCHI ROSSMAN Elly;Elly;elliebanana10th@gmail.com;Japan;English\r\nULUSOY Nedim Can;Nedim;nedimcanulusoy@gmail.com;Turkey;English, Hungarian\r\nXuan Qijian;Xuan;xjwjadon@gmail.com;China ?;?\r\nYUAN Gaopeng;Yuan;1277237374@qq.com;China;English\r\n'
```

vs

```
print(repr(content))
[b'Name;Short name;Email;Country;Other spoken languages\r\n', b'ABOUELHASSAN Shehab Ibrahim Adbelazin;?;dwedar909@gmail.com;?;?\r\n', b'AGHAEI HOSSEIN ABADI Mohammad Mehdi;Matt;mahdiaghaei355@gmail.com;Iran;English\r\n', b'AMIN Asjad;?;;?;?\r\n', b'ATILA Arda Burak;Arda;arda_atila@hotmail.com;Turkey;English\r\n', b'BELTRAN CASTRO Carlos Ricardo;Ricardo;crbeltrancas@gmail.com;Colombia;English, Chinese\r\n', b'Bhatti Muhammad Hasan;?;;?;?\r\n', b'CAKIR Alp Hazar;Alp;alphazarc@gmail.com;Turkey;English\r\n', b'DENG Zhihui;Deng;dzhfalcon0727@gmail.com;China;English\r\n', b'DURUER Ahmet Enes;Ahmet / kahverengi;hello@ahmetduruer.com;Turkey;English\r\n', b'ENKHZAYA Jagar;Jager;japman2400@gmail.com;Mongolia;English\r\n', b'GHAIBAH Sanaa;Sanaa;sanaagheibeh12@gmail.com;Syria;English\r\n', b'GUO Ruizheng;?;ruizhengguo@gmail.com;China;English\r\n', b'GURBANZADE Gurban;Qurban;gurbanzade01@gmail.com;Azeribaijan;English, Russian, Turkish\r\n', b'HASNAIN Syed Muhammad;Hasnain;syedhasnainhijazy313@gmail.com;Pakistan;?\r\n', b'ISMAYILOV Firdovsi;Firi;firiisi@gmail.com;Azeribaijan ?;English,Russian,Turkish\r\n', b'KINGRANI Muskan;Muskan;muskankingrani4@gmail.com;India;English\r\n', b'KOKO Susan Kekeli Ruth;Susan;susankoko3@gmail.com;Ghana;N/A\r\n', b'KOLA-OLALEYE Adeola Damilola;Adeola;inboxadeola@gmail.com;Nigeria;French\r\n', b'LEWIS Madison Buse;?;madisonbuse@yahoo.com;Turkey;Turkish\r\n', b'LI Ting;Ting;514053044@qq.com;China;English\r\n', b'MARUSENKO Svetlana;Svetlana;svetlana.maru@gmail.com;Russia;English, German\r\n', b'MOHANTY Cyrus;cyrus;cyrusmohanty5261@gmail.com;India;English\r\n', b'MOTHOBI Thabo Emmanuel;thabo;thabomothobi@icloud.com;South Africa;English\r\n', b'Nayudu Yashmit Vinay;?;;?;?\r\n', b'Purevsuren Davaadorj;?;Purevsuren.davaadorj99@gmail.com;Mongolia ?;English\r\n', b'SAJID Anoosha;Anoosha;anooshasajid12@gmail.com;Pakistan;English\r\n', b'SHANG Rongxiang;Xiang;1074482757@qq.com;China;English\r\n', b'SU Haobo;Su;2483851740@qq.com;China;English\r\n', b'TAKEUCHI ROSSMAN Elly;Elly;elliebanana10th@gmail.com;Japan;English\r\n', b'ULUSOY Nedim Can;Nedim;nedimcanulusoy@gmail.com;Turkey;English, Hungarian\r\n', b'Xuan Qijian;Xuan;xjwjadon@gmail.com;China ?;?\r\n', b'YUAN Gaopeng;Yuan;1277237374@qq.com;China;English\r\n']
```

Also, instead of hard-coding the charset as `utf-8`, you can use `response.headers.get_content_charset()`